# Angular 1.5: calling a method of a component inside ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, components

I have a component named `suggest` inside a nested loop:

```
<div ng-repeat="phrase in model.phrases track by $index">
    <div ng-repeat="word in phrase.words track by $index">
        <suggest phrase-index="$parent.$index" word-index="$index"></suggest>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to manipulate the component's data from the root scope. What would be the best way of doing this?

My main problem is finding the correct component instance by phrase-index and word-index. While normally I would write something like `$('suggest[phrase-index="0"]')`, it doesn't work in this case, since the attribute value is still `"$parent.$index"`.

The other part that's unclear is calling a method on a component after I find it. Right now I'm using $(element).children().scope() to get the scope reference and call a method on it, but the docs say that scope() should only be used for debugging. What would be a better way?

It is possible that I'm doing it all too $-y, and there's a much better way. I just don't want to over-engineer this with multiple components/services busy with passing method calls between layers.

Comment: can you provide more xode examples, how you call the method, are you using jquery?

Comment: "I just don't want to over-engineer this with multiple components/services busy with passing method calls between layers" -- why you use angular? why u use components? Go ahead with one html and one controller - you wont have any problems of "over-engineering"

Comment: @Fribu normally I would loop over all suggest components and call a method on each.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov if you know a solution that would solve my problem, please share it. By over-engineering I meant making it look "correct" by formal parameters, yet less maintainable than even having everything in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit an event on $rootScope and and call component method in the event lister defined in the component controller.

Somewhere in your application emit event with index value of required component instance:

```
$rootScope.$emit('suggestEvent', someIndexValue);
```

and in your component controller define the event listener calling component method if `phrase-index` is equal to index value passed in event:

```
 //inside suggest component controller
 $rootScope.$on('suggestEvent', function(index) {
       //call component method if 'index' value is equal to  component `phrase-index`
      if (this.phraseIndex === index) {
          this.someMethod();
      }
 })
```